# How to iterate through a string to extract and store specific contents several time

Tags: java

**Context**

I have a `String` which looks like a XPath:

`//img[@id='imgError' and @src='../plaf/images/default/menu/menu_down.gif' and @alt='Authorise' and @ref_element = 'Object/Common/Frames/frame1']`.

**Objective**

My objective is to extract all `@ref_element=...` element and switch in the corresponding frame.

XPath of `frame1` is `//frame[contains(@id, 'frame1') and contains(@name, 'frame1')]`.

So the expected result should be:

```
// switch into the frame thanks to xpath extracted before
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frame[contains(@id, 'frame1') and contains(@name, 'frame1')]"));
// do an action
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@id='imgError' and @src='../plaf/images/default/menu/menu_down.gif' and @alt='Authorise']").click()
```

I don't have any problem to get the XPath of `@ref_element` and switch in another frame.

However, I need help to find an algorithm to browse the initial string and extract `@ref_element=...`.

**Question**

Could you please help me to build this algorithm because I don't have any idea how to do... At least some clue?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get the question completely, but if you are looking for **Object/Common/Frames/frame1** out of **@ref_element='Object/Common/Frames/frame1'** then following snippet can help -

```
// this gives index of `'` after @ref_element
int x = "input".indexOf("@ref_element='");

// this gives index of `'` after x
int y = "input".indexOf("'", x + 1);

return "input".substring(x+1, y);
```

Please ignore if this does not solve your problem.